# Row number and partition in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in excel such as:

```
ID        | Fee
123456789 | 100
987654321 | 100
987654321 | 75
987654321 | 50
```

I need to calculate a fee reduction for the items that are not the max price. The spreadsheet is sorted by ID, then Fee in the fashion needed. What I do not know how to do is use a similar row_number() over(partition by) in excel that I would normally do in SQL

Desired output would be

```
ID        | Fee   | rn
123456789 | 100   | 1
987654321 | 100   | 1
987654321 | 75    | 2
987654321 | 50    | 3
```

Comment: @pnuts, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY fee DESC)` is a SQL Window Function. It's essentially establishing a counter, starting at 1, for each distinct ID and incrementing it for each fee, sorted descending. If ROW_NUMBER() comes up against duplicate fee's for the ID, it will continue to increment so the row_number for that ID is distinct.

Comment: My data looks like it does in the four sample records, the sql would really be something like `row_number() over(parition by id order by fee desc)`, but since the data lives in an excel woorksheet the sql statement is not valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a more complex formula one could just throw at the data without having to monkey with the data, but I think this may be an easier solution:

1. Sort the data by ID (smallest to largest) and Fee (Smallest to largest)
   [image]
2. Use formula `=Countif(A2:A5, A2)` to count how many times the same `id` appears in the data for the current cell and every cell below it. Copying this down to fill out the missing column.
   [image]

Comment: What I ended up doing was the following, in a separate column I did `=IF(B2=B3,1,0)` then in the adjacent column I did `=IF(B2=B1,N1+O1,1)`, it only works because everything is sorted in the order I need

Comment: @pnuts that gives 1 the whole way down

Comment: @JNevill I accepted because that will work with some possible extra sort

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator I ended up using your solution in your comment with an extra sort.

Answer (score 9):

This formula will do the job:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A2)),A2)
```

There is no need for sorting the data and you won't fall out of the range.

`ROW()` is used to make the range dynamic, so if we drag the formula down, `ROW()` will always give us ending point:

[image: screen of an excel table]

Comment: Why would `Row(A2)` be different than just 2?

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others. [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Dominique, if there was 2 instead of ROW() it would not make the range expandable. The whole idea here is to have "moving" range while progressing with the formula.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`; note that only the first $A$2 will not move.

Answer (score 1):

1. Arrange everything in column A (in any order).
2. In B1 type this : =IF(A1=A2, (B2+1),1), extent this over the entire column B.