# sql select record based on multiple "time" only

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I get following  table "myTable" in Excel.

| Time | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0:01:01 | Apple | 1 | 2 |
| 0:01:01 | Banana | 3 | 4 |
| 0:01:01 | Cherry | 5 | 6 |
| 0:02:01 | Apple | 11 | 12 |
| 0:02:01 | Banana | 13 | 14 |
| 0:02:01 | Cherry | 15 | 16 |
| 0:03:01 | Apple | 21 | 22 |
| 0:03:01 | Banana | 23 | 24 |
| 0:03:01 | Cherry | 25 | 26 |

Want to get it converted to

| Time | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0:01:01 | Apple | 1 | 2 | Banana | 3 | 4 | Cherry | 5 | 6 |
| 0:02:01 | Apple | 11 | 12 | Banana | 13 | 14 | Cherry | 15 | 16 |
| 0:03:01 | Apple | 21 | 22 | Banana | 23 | 24 | Cherry | 25 | 26 |

So far I tried following steps in vain

1. Find distinct "A"s value using "SELECT DISTINCT A FROM myTable"
2. Find distinct "time" value using "SELECT DISTINCT Time FROM myTable ORDER BY Time ASC"
3. For each value of "A", I was trying to get entry for each time
   "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A in ("Apple") AND Time in ("0:01:01", "0:02:01", "0:03:01")" -> This query fails
   My approach if for each value of "A" get the table and update excel sheet column wise. i.e. First query for "Apple" against all "time". Update this value in Excel. Second Query for "Banana" against all time" and update after Apple update

Any help please.

- Time column consists of Time only
- Using ADODB connection within EXCEL using VBA script. I presume ADODB uses MS SQL

Thanks

Note : *some of my past questions were not well received. Hence I will get blocked if I post similar questions. If you feel the same about this question, please do not mark it as wrong question. Instead do not answer this question. Thanks*

Comment: You say you have a table in Excel but then you also say this is in sql server. Where is the data actually at? Also, from what you claim you want the first two queries look like they would return what you want. The third one....I have no idea what you are trying to do there. And the conversion table bit makes no sense either.

Comment: Updated the query. Within Excel I use ADODB Connection. Hope ADODB uses MS SQL. 3rd query I will be running for each unique value in column "A" and saving it side-by-side in Excel

Comment: This is honestly a mess. You will need to use either a pivot or conditional aggregation. But how do you know that Apple is always first, banana is always second and cherry is always third? What happens when you add a fourth? fifth? This is not really manageable.

Comment: With my first query I will find distinct values in column "A". Using those distinct values I loop one after the other. I am not specific about order of distinct "A". In short as per my example I can start with APPLE or Banana Or cherry . Not specific about order

Comment: You don't want to use a loop for this kind of thing. Again go lookup how to use either conditional aggregation or pivot. This can and should be done with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a loop is the wrong way to go about. I would also avoid using column names like `time`. It is a datatype name and should be avoided as it just makes things more difficult. And in this case it is too ambiguous to be useful. What does the value indicate? TimeCreated? TimePurchased? TimeUpdated? SomeOtherTime? Also having the same column name multiple times indicates a design issue but I will let you sort that one out.

Here is how you would retrieve this information using conditional aggregation from your sample data.

```
declare @Something table
(
    MyTime time
    , A varchar(20)
    , B int
    , C int
)
insert @Something values
('0:01:01', 'Apple', 1, 2)
, ('0:01:01', 'Banana', 3, 4)
, ('0:01:01', 'Cherry', 5, 6)
, ('0:02:01', 'Apple', 11, 12)
, ('0:02:01', 'Banana', 13, 14)
, ('0:02:01', 'Cherry', 15, 16)
, ('0:03:01', 'Apple', 21, 22)
, ('0:03:01', 'Banana', 23, 24)
, ('0:03:01', 'Cherry', 25, 26);

with MyCte as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by s.MyTime order by s.B)
    from @Something s
)
select [Time] = max(c.MyTime)
    , A = max(case when c.RowNum = 1 then A end)
    , B = max(case when c.RowNum = 1 then B end)
    , C = max(case when c.RowNum = 1 then C end)
    , A = max(case when c.RowNum = 2 then A end)
    , B = max(case when c.RowNum = 2 then B end)
    , C = max(case when c.RowNum = 2 then C end)
    , A = max(case when c.RowNum = 3 then A end)
    , B = max(case when c.RowNum = 3 then B end)
    , C = max(case when c.RowNum = 3 then C end)
from MyCte c
group by c.MyTime
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am getting Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MyTime order by s.B) 

Seems ROW_Function() is not supported in EXCEL based SQL Query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270156/row-number-and-partition-in-excel

Comment: Well at one point this was tagged with sql server but I guess it changed at some point. To be honest the biggest challenge you have here is that you are trying to use a relation database for very non-relational concepts. Your output is denormalized and having lots of constraints about what technology to use is just making it harder.